# How to Remove index.php from URL in PHP

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to remove index.php from url but so far i couldn't succeed it. I'm using Wamp server on my local and Apache on remote server..
In local root directory, my project files are located in a subfolder like

```
www/project/index.php
```

I can access web pages like

`localhost/project/index.php/home`

`localhost/project/index.php/messages/?mId=3`

I just want to access it like

```
localhost/project/home
localhost/project/messages/?mId=3
```

I already tried some .htaccess rewrite rule but couldnt make it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you need to organize:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [NC,QSA,L]
</ifModule>
```

And then you will have everything as you need.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use url rewriting with a .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Put a .htaccess with this content in each subfolder.

Comment: Thanks Martin, it's working.. But one more question, I can still type url with index.php and not removing index.php. It's working when I type localhost/project/home but when i type /localhost/project/index.php/home it's still in there?

Comment: Also after .htaccess change $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] is just empty.. I was using it in index.php to calculate controller name fro url.

Comment: yeah, with this rewrite conditions, everything will be accessible in $_GET['url'] instead of PATH_INFO