# How make url of 127.0.0.1/index.php to 127.0.0.1?

Tags: php

I'm new to php. When i run the server and loads the index.php page, the url look like this 127.0.0.1/index.php

but i want to load the index.php page in main address 127.0.01 instead of 127.0.0.1/index.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Remove index.php from URL in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7934150/how-to-remove-index-php-from-url-in-php). This has little to do with PHP. You have to instruct your webserver to serve the `/` request to `index.php` file. If it's not already working.

Comment: Since its the index file, you can just access it as `127.0.0.1` directly.

Comment: If you type in your IP like "127.0.0.1" it will automatically load the index.html/.php

Answer (score 2):

You can use an htaccess file (**.htaccess**).
And set `DirectoryIndex index.php` for load your **index.php** without URL /index.php

Answer (score 1):

In the case of IIS Server, put following file in the root

**web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

   <system.webServer>

    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>

    <rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="RuleRemoveIndex" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true"/>
        </rule>
    </rules>
    </rewrite>

</system.webServer>

<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
</system.web>

</configuration>
```

Comment: this is in case of IIS server, if you can edit and point that :)

Comment: Sure, this is in the case of IIS server. Thanks @niklaz for this.

Answer (score 0):

if you have Apache server installed, and have access to main .conf file of your Apache instance, then put this in conf and restart Apache, or if you don't have, then in root directory put in .htaccess:

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.php3 index.html index.htm
</IfModule>
```

This will set directive that tells Apache which file will serve if a directory is accessed.

Answer (score 0):

You needn't do anything. If you put an index.php/.html in the directory, the browser would not show index.php in the url address.